# How to prevent data.table to force numeric variables into character variables without manually specifying these?

Tags: r, data.table, splitstackshape

Consider the following dataset:

```
dt <- structure(list(lllocatie = structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Assen", "Oosterwijtwerd", "Startenhuizen", "t-Zandt", "Tjuchem", "Winneweer"), class = "factor"), 
                 lat = c(52.992, 53.32, 53.336, 53.363, 53.368), 
                 lon = c(6.548, 6.74, 6.808, 6.765, 6.675), 
                 mag.cat = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                 places = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("", "Amen,Assen,Deurze,Ekehaar,Eleveld,Geelbroek,Taarlo,Ubbena", "Eppenhuizen,Garsthuizen,Huizinge,Kantens,Middelstum,Oldenzijl,Rottum,Startenhuizen,Toornwerd,Westeremden,Zandeweer", "Loppersum,Winneweer", "Oosterwijtwerd", "t-Zandt,Zeerijp"), class = "factor")),
            .Names = c("lllocatie", "lat", "lon", "mag.cat", "places"), 
            class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
            row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

When I want to split the strings in the last column into separate rows, I use (with `data.table` version *1.9.5+*):

```
dt.new <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))), by=list(lllocatie,lat,lon,mag.cat)]
```

However, when I use:

```
dt.new2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))), by=lllocatie]
```

I get the the same result except that all columns are forced into character variables. The problem is that for small datasets it is not a big problem to specify the variables that do not have to split in the `by` argument, but for datasets with many columns/variables it is. I know it is possible to do this with the `splitstackshape` package (as is mentioned by [@ColonelBeauvel in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31568609/2204410)), but I'm looking for a `data.table` solution as i want to chain more operations to this.

How can I prevent that without manually specifying the variables that do not have to be split in the `by` argument?

Comment: Use `type.convert=TRUE` argument for `tstrsplit()`.

Comment: If it's an issue of specifying a lot of variables, can you use something like `setdiff(names(dt),badcol)` to construct your `by` and `.SD`?

Comment: @Arun that worked (and it sounds like an answer :-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two solutions with `data.table`:

**1**: Use the `type.convert=TRUE` argument inside `tstrsplit()` as proposed by @Arun:

```
dt.new1 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE))), by=lllocatie]
```

**2**: Use `setdiff(names(dt),"places")` in the `by` argument as proposed by @Frank:

```
dt.new2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE))), by=setdiff(names(dt),"places")]
```

Both approaches give the same result:

```
> identical(dt.new1,dt.new2)
[1] TRUE
```

The advantage of the second solution is that when you have more thanone columns with string values, only the one you specify in `setdiff(names(dt),"places")` is being split (supposing you want only that specific one, in this case `places`, to split). The `splitstackshape` package also offers this advantage.

Answer (score 5):

It's exactly a job for `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(dt, 'places', ',')
```

Comment: Thanx, I know I can do that with `splitstackshape` (but forgot to mention that in the question), but wanted a `data.table` solution as want to chain more stuff to that ( a +1 though).

Comment: @Jaap the `splitstackshape` is a `data.table` based package. But ofcourse Arun provided the correct answer. I'm surprised you didn't know that though, as we discussed this over a week when I eventually filed a bug report regarding `type.convert` and it eventually will be fixed in the next release of R :)

Comment: @Jaap, if you can import `data.table` you can import `splitstackshape` ! and you can chain operation after the cSplit!

Comment: Didn't know that `splitstackshape` is a `data.table` based package. Consequently it's logical that you can chain operations after `cSplit`. I consider this as a learning moment :-)